# Finding all the display methods from a table

Tags: reflection, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I need to put all the display methods from a table into cache so instead of typing that manually (there are a lot of display method) I tried to do it dynamically, i.e. browsing every method of the table and then checking if it is a display method to get the `tablemethodstr()` and putting it into the cache with `cacheAddMethod()` on a form datasource.

However I could not find a way to filter methods using their attributes so I was wondering if it was even possible to do so in AX 2009 using pure X++?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote a job that might help you get what you need.  I'm not entirely sure of the question, but you should just be able to run this:

```
static void Job46(Args _args)
{
    DictTable       dictTable;
    int             i;
    MethodInfo      methodInfo;
    SysDictTable    dt = new sysDictTable(tableNum(Address));
    ;

    dictTable = new dictTable(TableNum(Address));

    for (i=1; i<dt.objectMethodCnt(); i++)
    {
        methodInfo = dt.objectMethodObject(i);

        if (methodInfo.displayType() == DisplayFunctionType::Get)
            info(strfmt("Found Display: %1 - %2 - %3", methodInfo.displayType(), enum2str(methodInfo.returnType()), methodInfo.name()));
        else
            info(strfmt("Not Display: %1 - %2 - %3", methodInfo.displayType(), enum2str(methodInfo.returnType()), methodInfo.name()));
    }
}
```

A line of note would be the "methodInfo.displayType() == DisplayFunctionType::Get"

EDIT: May need to be "<=" instead of "<"...didn't test that.  You'll figure it out.